# Creating one client per each consumer

Tags: nats.io

In one my projects I need to implement health checks for microservices. NATS already has an Http endpoint for that but it only provides information about connected clients and not consumers. So I have come across this idea that if I create one client per each consumer and name it accordingly using NATS options, I can use that monitoring interface out of the box.

But my question is that, if the number of clients increase, does it cause any performance issues? Would this workaround cause any other problems in production environment?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is if you should split clients into different consumers, then no, this should not be the way. For many clients to use one consumer is a common use case.
You could build this heath check for yourself if you really want to. Maybe an approach to monitor the consumers of specific clients makes more sense.